# Alternative spice model of TI CD4066b

Tags: simulation, orcad

I'm busy working on a uni practical in which we are required to construct a chopper modulator and I'm busy creating a schematic in orCad to run some simulations. I'll be using a Texas Instruments CD4066b CMOS quad bilateral switch and was hoping to find a spice model on the TI site but unfortunately there isn't one. My question is what could I use as an alternative in orCad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about *Simulating the CD4066 Quad Bilateral Switch With LTspice*: [http://www.embeddedcomponents.com/blogs/2011/12/cd4066-ltspice-simulation/](https://web.archive.org/web/20180403102015/http://www.embeddedcomponents.com/blogs/2011/12/cd4066-ltspice-simulation/)? (archived link)

Or use faster switches with lower Ron here: http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/simulation-models/spice-models.html.
Bipolar supplies are useful.

Maybe the ADG4613 but the reason they don't have a model was the specs were so loose and supply sensitive (old technology).